# Furry's theorem in Electroweak and strong interactions

Tags: standard-model, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions, electroweak, cp-violation

We can think of [Furry's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furry%27s_theorem) as the consequence of $CP$ invariance of $QED$. For parity, the vector bilinear changes sign, hence, under charge conjugation, it should. The vacuum is $C$-invariant, hence odd number of vector bilinears vanish. This is true for the quark-quark-gluon interaction as well. Hence, for triangle quark loop connected with three gluons vanish. Now consider the following diagram:

[image]

It is actually planner, hence forget the cut. So, here the fermion loop is connected by two gluons and one $Z$ boson. After spontaneous symmetry breaking, the diagonal part of the quark doublet kinetic term gives the $Z-q-q$ interaction, hence it is $CP$ invariant, and parity violating;hence charge conjugation violating. So, we should expect this diagram to be zero, according to Furry's theorem. Is it true? I have not found any suitable reference.